# VS Code Shortcut for navigating inside Command Palette and File Picker

Tags: visual-studio-code

In vs code, command palette and file picker can be opened with ctrl+shift+p and ctrl+p respectively, I want to set custom shortcut for moving down and up inside the list.
like alt+j(up/previous) and alt+k(down/next)

[image]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To navigate up and down in the command palette or any quickOpen panel:

```
{
    "key": "alt+j",
    "command": "workbench.action.quickOpenSelectNext",
    "when": "inQuickOpen"
},
{
    "key": "alt+k",
    "command": "workbench.action.quickOpenSelectPrevious",
    "when": "inQuickOpen"
},
```

To navigate and **trigger** whichever command you end on:

```
{
    "key": "alt+j",
    "command": "workbench.action.quickOpenNavigateNext",
    "when": "inQuickOpen"
},
{
    "key": "alt+k",
    "command": "workbench.action.quickOpenNavigatePrevious",
    "when": "inQuickOpen"
},
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using VSCode **1.38.1**, using this u can do the following:

1. open `keyboard shortcuts`, by clicking the gear-icon
2. search for `Move Line Up or Down`
3. on the search results *hover* over the result, edit icon will appear... click on it
4. set the new keymap

Comment: and what is the exact item to be mapped ?

Comment: sorry, my assumption was wrong..! I go through the `keybindings.json` file & try to add the keymap as: `[ { "key" : "...", "command" : "...", "when" : "..." } ]`, but not worked. As, I set the commad to something like this: **workbench.commandPallete.commands.action.<action>**. But it's not present in VSCode's defined action(s) set, so not worked as expected. So, what u can do is to write the logic or copy-paste **"editor.action.moveLinesUpAction"** code into the following to work. Or u may go through VSCode docs [here](https://vscode-docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/customization/keybindings)