# VSCode - How to use Shift+Tab to select the previous item in the command palette?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-keybinding

I used the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58080196/vs-code-shortcut-for-navigating-inside-command-palette-and-file-picker#answer-58082645) to the related question and other similar ones to set keybindings for navigating through the command palette as follows.

```json
{
  "key": "tab",
  "command": "workbench.action.quickOpenSelectNext",
  "when": "inQuickOpen"
},
{
  "key": "shift+tab",
  "command": "workbench.action.quickOpenSelectPrevious",
  "when": "inQuickOpen"
},
```

<kbd>Tab</kbd> key works fine to select the next item but <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> doesn't do any action.
When I checked the [keyboard shortcuts troubleshooting](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_troubleshooting-keybindings), I noticed that when the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key is down in the command palette, the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key is ignored and isn't received.

Is there any way to set <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> for this?

I couldn't find any generic shortcuts to use rather than <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>.
I have to mention that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> are reserved keybindings so I don't want to use them for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to trigger `workbench.action.quickOpenSelectPrevious"` like you want.

See [Shift+Tab keybinding does not work in quick pick](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/180862) - the issue is reported and open/unresolved.

Of course, just the arrow keys do work in the quickOpen box.